# Can we merge two equal questions that hold different valid answers as approach to the problem?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, related-questions, exact-duplicates

I found out that a question where I have provided an answer had a sibling, were has, both questions ask about the same issue, but the answers provided give different approaches to get the intended information:

- [How can I determine my Galaxy Nexus model variant?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28226/16265)
  *asked Aug 24 '12 at 13:50*
- [How to find out the variant of my Galaxy Nexus?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26157/16265)
  *asked Jul 20 '12 at 10:58*

Can all the answers be merged under a single question since they present different ways of finding the information?

<sup>Or should one be closed as duplicate of the other?</sup>

Comment: Those should be merged, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch. The questions have been merged.